# Moodle display moodle_exception Error on form post

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to `moodle` and trying to customize my `course` creation in `moodle`.

I validated by `moodle_form` data in a function and from there I need to throw an error which will be displayed after the form (**`course/edit_form.php`)** is submitted. I tried the moodle way, as they have done:

```
throw new moodle_exception('refresher_value_less_than_one', '', '', $data->refresh_value);
```

I expected it to receive the error at the form page. It showed be the error string but not inside the form, but on a blank page.

Any idea, how to catch this exception in form.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show an error within the form, then you need to create a function within your form class called 'validation($data, $files)'. Within this form, you need to check the values in the array $data, then return an array of error messages, indexed by the form field that the error should display beside.

For example, if you had a field called 'myfield', you could check the contents of $Data['myfield'] and, if there was a problem, return array('myfield' => get_string('myfielderror', 'myplugin')).

Throwing an exception will immediately halt the execution of the page and output only that error message.

Comment: I tried it.. but this validation function is being called, before the form is submitted.

Comment: The validation function is called when you call $form->get_data(). It checks all the data is valid, before you attempt to process it. As it contains all the data submitted to the form, there should be enough information to do any required checks, before you go on to start processing the data.